# Capture an optional group within another capture

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

Given input like

```
${first_name}, ${last_name}, ${create_date:(Y-m-d)}, ${submit_date:(Y-m-d)}
```

I can use `\${(.*)}` to capture everything between the brackets.  When a suffix appears like on the dates in the example, I want to capture that as its own group.  How can I do that with one regular expression?

Comment: Can you show your code and make it clear the result you expect from a sample string.

Comment: Where is the `SOMETHING` in your example?

Comment: `\$\{(.*?)\}` will already capture that. Or did you mean `\$\{(.*?)(?::(.*?))?\}` to capture the "key/value" separately?

Comment: Yes @NiettheDarkAbsol, this is exacly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
\$\{([^:, ]*(?::\(([^)]*)\))?)\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/149),,, in which total value(string) inside curely-brace is captured to `group 1`, and optional value(string) is captured to `group 2`.

and you can try this too if you don't want inclusive relation between group 1 and 2,

```
\$\{([^:, ]*)(?::\(([^)]*)\))?\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/150)

Answer (score 0):

I think your original approach `\${(.*)}` has a small issue, which is that your wildcard matcher `.*` includes the `}` symbol, which you don't want to match.  In fact, once you begin capturing it's the only thing you don't want to match, so we change:

```
.*      // match anything zero or more times
```

to

```
[^}]*   // match anything that isn't } zero or more times
```

But you want to match everything inside the curly braces unless it's got the structure `some_underscored_words:(desired-text)`, in which case you want to match `desired-text`.

I'd solve this by making use of the `?` operator, which you place after a capture group to define it as optional.  The `?` is greedy, which means that it'll try to match first, and only if it fails will it try to process matches without the optional pattern.

To think about this, it helps to rephrase what you want using greedy thinking.

Instead of saying:

> I want to capture whatever's inside of the curly braces and also
>   capture the value within the parentheses if they exist

Change it to:

> I want to capture the value that's nested inside the parentheses
>   inside the curly braces, but if that doesn't exist I'll just have
>   whatever's inside the braces.

Turning that into a regex, I get this:

```
\${([a-z_]+:\()?([^\)}]*)
```

Breaking it down:

Start by looking for the unique symbol:

```
${
```

Try to match against the nested pattern:

```
([a-z_]+:\()?
```

This matches `any_underscored_lowercase_words` one or more times (`+`) followed by a `:(`

Now we match zero or more letters that aren't either of our closing tags `)` or `}`

```
([^\)}]*)
```

Being greedy, it goes straight for the nested pattern.  Failing that, the match falls back to capturing anything that isn't either of the closing symbols.

The one scenario I can think of where this won't work is this:

```
${seems like a normal match) wait where did these letters go?}
```

Which will give you "seems like a normal match".

Answer (score 0):

To build the best/fastest pattern you need to allow the regex engine to perform in a greedy fashion as much as possible that means using quantifiers like `*` and `+` without a trailing `?`.

The following pattern will require the first capture group (output column `[1]`) and make the second capture group optional (output column `[2]`).

Suggested Pattern: `~\$\{([^:}]+)(?::([^}]+))?~` ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpbIN9/1))

```
~             #starting pattern delimiter
\$\{          #match a dollar sign then opening curly bracket
(             #start Capture Group #1
  [^:}]+      #match one or more non-colon, non-closing curly bracket characters
)             #end Capture Group #1
(?:           #start non-capturing group
  :           #match a colon
  (           #start Capture Group #2
    [^}]+     #match one or more non-closing curly brackets
  )           #end Capture Group #2
)?            #end non-capturing group and allow zero or one occurence of the group
~             #end pattern delimiter
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2vTTY))

```
$string = '${first_name}, ${last_name}, ${create_date:(Y-m-d)}, ${submit_date:(Y-m-d)}';
var_export(preg_match_all('~\$\{([^:}]+)(?::([^}]+))?~', $string, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER) ? $out : 'fail');
```

You can disregard the `[0]` (fullstring) match column.  You are only interested in the first and second capture groups.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '${first_name',
    1 => 'first_name',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '${last_name',
    1 => 'last_name',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '${create_date:(Y-m-d)',
    1 => 'create_date',
    2 => '(Y-m-d)',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '${submit_date:(Y-m-d)',
    1 => 'submit_date',
    2 => '(Y-m-d)',
  ),
)
```